# Ruby-Selenium WebDriver 3.142.6: Unable to upload file due to "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownCommandError:"

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir

Unable to upload the file using `selenium-webdriver (3.142.6)` gem in Ruby

Tech stack:

> selenium-webdriver (3.142.6)
>
> Chrome Version : 77
>
> Chrome driver: 77

**Error Message:**

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownCommandError: unknown command: unknown command: session/xxxsession_idXXX/se/file
Backtrace:
       Ordinal0 [0x00FDEB13+1501971]
       Ordinal0 [0x00F5F6D1+980689]
        Ordinal0 [0x00EE765F+489055]
        Ordinal0 [0x00E9618E+156046]
        Ordinal0 [0x00E95FF4+155636]
        Ordinal0 [0x00E7220E+8718]
  Ordinal0 [0x00E72626+9766]
  Ordinal0 [0x00E72C10+11280]
 Ordinal0 [0x00F78F37+1085239]
       GetHandleVerifier [0x0107D7ED+503293]
       GetHandleVerifier [0x0107D580+502672]
       GetHandleVerifier [0x010846AC+531644]
       GetHandleVerifier [0x0107DFFA+505354]
       Ordinal0 [0x00F70606+1050118]
       Ordinal0 [0x00F7047F+1049727]
       Ordinal0 [0x00E7204B+8267]
  Ordinal0 [0x00E71D7C+7548]
  GetHandleVerifier [0x013CD83C+3976780]
      BaseThreadInitThunk [0x755738F4+36]
 RtlUnicodeStringToInteger [0x77375E13+595]
  RtlUnicodeStringToInteger [0x77375DDE+542]
```

Seems to be the upload is broken with this version of gem.

Code used to upload the file (watir with cheezy)

```
@browser.file_field(xpath: "//*[contains(text(), 'Upload')]/input[@type='file']").set(complete_path_to_file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root Cause:** `w3c` browser capability status

**Explanation:** When `w3c:true` selenium webdriver is throwing this error. This might be because of Selenium 3 is not at fully supporting w3c implementation.

**Solution1:** Simple solution would be making `w3c:false` if you don't have any dependencies based of the `w3c` capability.

**Solution2:** If solution 1 doesn't work then you have to update the `selenium-webdriver-3.142.6\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\w3c\commands.rb` file. check for below line and then update it.

> upload_file: [:post, 'session/:session_id/se/file']

Updating this line to

**upload_file: [:post, 'session/:session_id/file']**

**Conclusion:** Would prefer solution 1 until Selenium 4 is rolled out. If you go with solution 2 there is possibility of test failure when you try to run them on the machine where this change is not pushed/ the file might be set back with `bundle install`.

You can use the method overright approach to go with solution but personally I feel it's too much.

Posted the solution to SeleniumHQ, will submit Pull Request to SeleniumHQ once got confirmation. So that you don't face this issue in later version of Selenium Ruby WebDriver.

Comment: Hi, use watir which is the wrapper for selenium ruby binding.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Rajagopalan. Yeah, using watir. However, internally Watir will point to the same file that I have mentioned above . You will find the `@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(*selenium_args)` line in `browser.rb` file under watir implementation.

Comment: Yes, I know you will face the same problem . Now delete this question and post again using watir tag. People will come to help you.

Comment: Please include your code. In WATIR, you will have different syntax. To upload the file, you have to write, `b.file_field(id: 'something').Set 'filepath'`

Comment: upon further investigation, `w3c:true` capability is the one which is causing this issue. If we mark `w3:false` in the browser capabilities then the issue is not happening.

Comment: Ok then, seems like you found a solution

Comment: Kind of, submitted the information to SeleniumHQ. I will submit a pull request to SeleniumHQ once they confirm. Thansk for your time Rajagopalan.

Comment: Here the selenium [issue comment](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7666#issuecomment-540940600) that helped me resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

the core problem is that the webdriver for chrome uses a non-w3c standard url for handling file uploads.
when uploading a file, the webdriver uses the `/se/file` url path to upload.
this path (a.k.a. command) is supported by the selenium server. hence, the docker image provided by selenium works fine.
as soon as we use `chromedriver` directly, the upload fails.
find more info in this [github issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10352) and the linked issues within.

in order to solve this, we can force the webdriver to use the standard-compliant url by overriding the `:upload_file` key in `Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Bridge::COMMANDS`.
since, the initialization of this the `COMMANDS` constant does not happen when the module is loaded, we can override the `attach_file` method to make sure the constant is set correctly. here the hacky code:

```rb
module Capybara::Node::Actions
  alias_method :original_attach_file, :attach_file

  def attach_file(*args, **kwargs)
    implement_hacky_fix_for_file_uploads_with_chromedriver
    original_attach_file(*args, **kwargs)
  end

  def implement_hacky_fix_for_file_uploads_with_chromedriver
    return if @hacky_fix_implemented
    original_verbose, $VERBOSE = $VERBOSE, nil # ignore warnings

    cmds = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Bridge::COMMANDS.dup
    cmds[:upload_file] = [:post, "session/:session_id/file"]
    Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Bridge.const_set(:COMMANDS, cmds)
    $VERBOSE = original_verbose
    @hacky_fix_implemented = true
  end
end
```

by the way, finding the root cause was difficult, because when the error happens the capybara gem catches the error and tries to raise it again. however, when re-raising it uses an error constant that does not exists. I worked around it by using `StandardError` in `gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/selenium/nodes/chrome_node.rb +109`. Only then the error search could continue. maybe this could be worth an issue on its own.

Comment: Can confirm this works when using the selenium-webdriver gem (v 4.7.1) and capybara (v 3.38), with rspec tests running in a docker container, and chromedriver running on the host as a remote driver. Thanks so much for the fix!!

Comment: Can once again confirm that this continues to work after upgrading to selenium-webdriver v4.11 (new version with built-in driver management, [obviating need for webdrivers gem](https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers)) and capybara v3.39.2 (for compatibility with newer selenium version). Cheers