# In Selenium webdriver, for remote Firefox how to use OSS bridge instead of w3c bridge for handshaking

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara, selenium-firefoxdriver, selenoid

I am using selenoid for remote browser testing in ruby.
In that I am using 'selenium-webdriver', 'capybara', 'rspec' for automation. And I am using attach_file method for uploading file to browser
I want to upload file on Firefox and Chrome browser but it raises error on both;

In chrome

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownCommandError: unknown command: unknown command: session/***8d32e045e3***/se/file

In firefox

> unexpected token at 'HTTP method not allowed'

So After searching I found the solution for chrome which is to set w3c option false in caps['goog:chromeOptions'] > ***caps['goog:chromeOptions'] = {w3c: false}***
So now chrome is using *OSS bridge* for handshaking but I don't know how to do it in Firefox. Similar solution is not available for Firefox.
My browser capabilities are following:

```
if ENV['BROWSER'] == 'firefox'
    caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new
    caps['browserName'] = 'firefox'
    # caps['moz:firefoxOptions'] = {w3c: false} ## It is not working
  else
    caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new
    caps["browserName"] = "chrome"
    caps["version"] = "81.0"
    caps['goog:chromeOptions'] = {w3c: false}
  end
    caps["enableVNC"] = true
    caps["screenResolution"] = "1280x800"
    caps['sessionTimeout'] = '15m'

  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|  
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :remote,
    :desired_capabilities => caps,
    :url => ENV["REMOTE_URL"] || "http://*.*.*.*:4444/wd/hub"
    )
  end

  Capybara.configure do |config|  
   config.default_driver = :selenium
  end
```

Comment: please check this question, I posted a workaround there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296774/ruby-selenium-webdriver-3-142-6-unable-to-upload-file-due-to-seleniumwebdriv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. There is bug in selenium server which run on java so I have to change my selenium-webdriver gem version 3.142.7 and monkey-patch.
You can find more information [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8570) about the bug and resolution.

For now I have to change my gem and monkey patch the selenium-webdriver-3.142.7\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\w3c\commands.rb file. check for below line which is on line no 150.

**upload_file: [:post, 'session/:session_id/se/file']**

and update it to

```
upload_file: [:post, 'session/:session_id/file']
```

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar issue with rails 7. the issue is connected with the w3c standard. the core problem is that the webdriver for chrome uses a non-w3c standard url for handling file uploads. when uploading a file, the webdriver uses the `/se/file` url path to upload. this path is only  supported by the selenium server. subsequently, the docker image provided by selenium works fine. yet, if we use `chromedriver`, the upload fails. [more info](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10352).

we can solve this, by forcing the webdriver to use the standard-compliant url by overriding the `:upload_file` key in `Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Bridge::COMMANDS`. since, the initialization of this the COMMANDS constant does not happen when the module is loaded, we can override the `attach_file` method to make sure the constant is set correctly. here the hacky code:

```rb
module Capybara::Node::Actions
  alias_method :original_attach_file, :attach_file

  def attach_file(*args, **kwargs)
    implement_hacky_fix_for_file_uploads_with_chromedriver
    original_attach_file(*args, **kwargs)
  end

  def implement_hacky_fix_for_file_uploads_with_chromedriver
    return if @hacky_fix_implemented
    original_verbose, $VERBOSE = $VERBOSE, nil # ignore warnings

    cmds = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Bridge::COMMANDS.dup
    cmds[:upload_file] = [:post, "session/:session_id/file"]
    Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Bridge.const_set(:COMMANDS, cmds)
    $VERBOSE = original_verbose
    @hacky_fix_implemented = true
  end
end
```

Comment: I can't believe this worked. You're seriously the real mvp.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox images we support `/session/<id>/file` API by adding Selenoid binary which emulates this API instead of Geckodriver (which does not implement it).

Comment: I didn't got you, how to provide the API and where

Comment: Everything is working only file upload is not working and giving error which is 'HTTP method not allowed'